email needed to be reviewed. I am not getting emails from our civi account
I am not getting the emails from civi. Who can help me review? I am doing exactly the same selecting group to email and then sent. However, I am not getting the ones from my team from Jack or Maddy for example.

can you get your team to check that they have set up spf, dkim and dmarc if this question is about deliverability issues
